# How come `par` uses only one core but faster?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to test the `parallel` package, specifically the `par` function. I wrote a simple program to test whether parallelism would speed up an otherwise sequential program.

So here I wrote two scripts, first sequential:

```
import Control.Parallel

n = 600000000

main = print $ pseq (mod (sum [1..n]) 5) (mod (sum [1..n]) 5)
```

second parallel:

```
import Control.Parallel

n = 600000000

main = print $ par (mod (sum [1..n]) 5) (mod (sum [1..n]) 5)
```

And I compiled each one using `ghc -O2` and ran them, and then measured the running time using GNU `time`. Here is what I got:

Sequential:

```
User time (seconds): 13.79
System time (seconds): 0.04
Percent of CPU this job got: 99%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:13.85
```

Parallel:

```
User time (seconds): 6.89
System time (seconds): 0.05
Percent of CPU this job got: 99%
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:06.97
```

which is interesting but perplexing: how come the parallel version is two times faster, but used only one core?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Why did it only use one core?

Because you used the non-threaded runtime. Compile with `-threaded` to take advantage of the fancy new threaded runtime. But because of the answer to the second question, this won't help you on this microbenchmark: you've only written one core's worth of computation to do.

> Why did it go faster?

Because it computed less stuff: since the first argument to `par` is never used by the second argument, it gets stuffed into a spark that never gets demanded and hence never gets forced to do its work. On the other hand, `pseq` *always* does the work needed for its first argument, even when that value isn't used by its second argument.